# Key error while plotting a bar graph using Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have been facing one issue while I am trying to plot a bar graph using the matplotlib library.

Please find the sample data below

[Sample Data Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3De8U.png)

```
count_movies_year = n_db.groupby('release_year').agg({'title':'count'}).rename(columns={'title':'no_of_titles'})
count_movies_year.reset_index()
```

I have written the above code and did the group_by on certain cases and renamed the column in the dataframe that I have in place. Now after this I wanted to plot a bar graph of the same using the matplotlib and I have written the below code

```
plt.bar(count_movies_year['release_year'],count_movies_year['no_of_titles'])
plt.xlabel('release_year')
plt.ylabel('no_of_titles')
plt.show()
```

but, when I do this I have some errors in place and the key_error shows me 'release_year'. Can I know what is wrong over here as I am new to Python and Matplotlib understanding. Can someone guide me where exactly things are going wrong so that I can correct them next time?

Comment: Hello, can you edit your question and add a sample of your data ? see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: @AlexisG - I have added the Snip of the sample data as an image, you can have a look at it.

Comment: Please use text instead of an image. It's easier with a text, to reproduce the error you encounter

Comment: @AlexisG - I'd do that from next time, by text you meant to say tabular format right ?

Comment: tabular text is better, but the best is an example dataframe that we can directly run. For example : `df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2])`

Answer (score 0):

When doing a `group_by`, the column "release_year" no longer exist in you Dataframe, since it's now the index.

You have multiple solution :

---

using a `reset_index` as you did, but you should reattribute it to your variable

```
count_movies_year = count_movies_year.reset_index()
```

---

or use the `inplace` parameter

```
count_movies_year.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

---

use the `.index` directly in your plot

```
plt.bar(count_movies_year.index, count_movies_year['no_of_titles'])
```